LangGraph Error - Invalid Tool Calls when using AzureChatOpenAI
I'm following the LangGraph tutorial (from LangGraph) and I'm getting an error when switching from "ChatOpenAI" to "AzureChatOpenAI". This is the code example from the website:
from langchain_openai import AzureChatOpenAI
from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
import os

from langgraph.graph import MessagesState
from langchain_core.messages import HumanMessage, SystemMessage

from langgraph.graph import START, StateGraph
from langgraph.prebuilt import tools_condition
from langgraph.prebuilt import ToolNode
from IPython.display import Image, display

load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), override=True)
  

This is the only change I've done, I've modified how to initialize the LLM (I am using AzureChatOpen AI) instead of ChatOpenAI 4o model.
llm = AzureChatOpenAI(
                openai_api_version=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_VERSION"),
                azure_deployment=os.getenv("DEPLOYMENT_NAME"),
                azure_endpoint=os.getenv("AZURE_OPENAI_ENDPOINT"), 
                temperature=0,
            )

Then the remain code:
def multiply(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Multiply a and b.

    Args:
        a: first int
        b: second int
    """
    return a * b

def add(a: int, b: int) -> int:
    """Adds a and b.

    Args:
        a: first int
        b: second int
    """
    return a + b
      

tools = [add, multiply]

llm_with_tools = llm.bind_tools(tools)


sys_msg = SystemMessage(content="You are a helpful assistant tasked with performing arithmetic on a set of inputs.")

def assistant(state: MessagesState):
   return {"messages": [llm_with_tools.invoke([sys_msg] + state["messages"])]}

# Graph
builder = StateGraph(MessagesState)

builder.add_node("assistant", assistant)
builder.add_node("tools", ToolNode(tools))

builder.add_edge(START, "assistant")
builder.add_conditional_edges(
    "assistant",
    tools_condition,
)
builder.add_edge("tools", "assistant")
react_graph = builder.compile()

And this is the call (how to reproduce the error):
messages = [HumanMessage(content="Add 3 and 4. Multiply the output by 2. Using the local tool")]

messages = react_graph.invoke({"messages": messages})

print the result:
for m in messages['messages']:
    m.pretty_print()

And this is the error I get:


multiply and add are missing the @tool decorator, no?

@cottontail, I get the same message as the tool decorator.
